# Fade out in ReactCSSTransitionGroup not working

Tags: css, reactjs

So I am trying to fade out (transition exit/leave) after 15 seconds. The fade in is working fine but the fade out isn't. Why is that the case? Here's my code

```
{this.state.reachedRSS ? [

                Object.keys(this.state.items).map((key) =>
                    <div>
                        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example"
                            transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
                            transitionEnter={false} transitionLeave={true}
                            transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}>

                            <h5><a href={this.state.link[key]}>{this.state.items[key]}</a></h5>
                            <h6>{this.state.description[key]}</h6>
                        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    </div>
                )
            ]
                : null}

            {
                this.state.reachedHTML ?
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example"
                        transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
                        transitionEnter={false} transitionLeave={true}
                            transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}>
                        {<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.body }} />}
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    : null
            }
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
}
.example-leave {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Your component unmounts before it can animate

Since unmounting happens instantly your component is instantly swapped out for `null`.

You should trigger your leaving animation via the state change and then unmount the component on completion.

Comment: Can that be done in the same transition? State changing of leave and also for enter?

Comment: You should be able to do thins in the same animation. But another point, do not unmount your transition group, only unmount the inner part of your transition group. Because the transition group works by add-in and removing things from its child components